# AWS SAM APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent HttpMethod not set when starting API locally

Tags: aws-lambda, sam, aws-http-api

I created an application with a `AWS::SERVERLESS::FUNCTION`, which has an HttpApi Event attached to it. I thought it would be a good idea to create one lambda per resource, so e.g. Post, Get and Put on /customer are all handled by a single lambda, which decides which action to take using

```java
switch (input.getHttpMethod()) {
    case "GET": ...
    case "POST: ...
}
```

So now coming to my problem: When starting an application using `sam local start-api` my lambda gets called correctly, but neither `input.getHttpMethod()` nor `input.getRequestContext().getHttpMethod()` is set.

Given that SAM supports multiple HttpApi events, failing to provide the http method when running the application locally mitigates local development virtually completely. Am I doing something wrong, or is this really not working? I'm using Java btw, I can't tell if this problem exists using other languages as well.

Just in Case:
Is my "one lambda per resource" approach wrong, should every single action have its own lambda?

Comment: This is also the case in python btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. HttpApi uses "PayloadFormatVersion: 2.0" as default. `input` was of type `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent`, but this represents format 1.0, I had to use `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayV2HTTPEvent` to get it to work.
This fails silently because instances are just constructed from json input, and several fields are the same among both classes.